# Telephone number in Main Menu

Tags: joomla-3.x

I was hoping for some advice. A user has asked for a telephone number to be implemented in the space between the main menu and right menu (See screenshot)[image] IN the space between Contact and Book Now. I have implemented this as a menu item (text separator) but this doesn't give me many options in way of css styling. I was hoping for some suggestions as to a better method for implementing this, possibly to allow for an icon to be used also?

Any ideas are very welcome.

Regards
Donna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggybacking on Max, I would do a external link and you can use the syntax **tel:1231231234** to make it a clickable link for mobile.

For the icon, you can use css to add that.  The selector will depend on template but as an example:

`.menu li.item100 a:before {font-family:FontAwesome;content:"\f023";}`

You will have to play with the formatting a bit.  If you can't find how to call that menu item in the CSS, post the URL and we can help you find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try option to external link. 
In addres url you complete with "#"

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @YellowWebMonkey's answer, but you can just add classes, for styling or icons, directly to the menu item itself.

[image]